# PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, database, triggers, oracle10g

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_DecreaseQuantity   
AFTER INSERT   
ON V_SALE FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN     
  UPDATE VEHICLE    
     SET V.V_QUANTITY=(SELECT CASE    
                              WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >= S.QUANTITY AND
                                   V.VEHICLE_ID = S.VEHICLE_ID_FK 
                              THEN V.V_QUANTITY = V.V_QUANTITY-S.QUANTITY    
                              WHEN V.V_QUANTITY < S.QUANTITY 
                              THEN V.V_QUANTITY = S.QUANTITY   
                         FROM VEHICLE V,
                              V_SALE S    
                        WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID=S.VEHICLE_ID_FK
                       )   
   WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID = :NEW.VEHICLE_ID_FK;  
END;
```

We have an `autoGallery` database and tables are in it.
There are two tables as `V_SALE` and `VEHICLE` that must be controlled. When I sale a vehicle I want to control the number of vehicles and then decrease the number or not.

```
Vehicle(
   Vehicle_ID Primary key, 
   V_QUANTITY 
   ...
)

V_SALE(
  VEHICLE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY, 
  QUANTITY 
  ...
)
```

I got the following errors:

```
Compilation failed, line 5 (16:03:48) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
Compilation failed, line 2 (16:03:48) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: doesnt the CASE need an END

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov thanks for editing

Answer (score 1):

A proper CASE statement has to end with END. And you cannot have an equal sign in the THEN clause, neither as a comparison nor as an assigment.

```
CASE 
    WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >= S.QUANTITY AND V.VEHICLE_ID = S.VEHICLE_ID_FK 
        THEN V.V_QUANTITY - S.QUANTITY 
    WHEN V.V_QUANTITY < S.QUANTITY 
        THEN S.QUANTITY
END
```

Comment: Yes, your right. The UPDATE statement has more mistakes than I thought.

Comment: @Codo I also tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" could mean: Returns the wrong results, causes an error when run, causes an error when compiled, blows up the computer etc. Would you mind being more specific and telling the exect error message if you got one?

Comment: @Codo I am sorry.I am getting the following errors:(Compilation)PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop

Comment: @Codo I couldn't write the whole error log because it is a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

try giving alias like this :

```
UPDATE VEHICLE V    
     SET V.V_QUANTITY=CASE WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >= :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN V.V_QUANTITY-:NEW.QUANTITY    
                                  WHEN V.V_QUANTITY < :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN :NEW.QUANTITY   
                              END
   WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID = :NEW.VEHICLE_ID_FK;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It is work.I am a bit changing it.Again Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `'CASE WHEN...END'` Syntax is wrong

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_DecreaseQuantity   
AFTER INSERT   
ON V_SALE FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN     
      UPDATE VEHICLE    
      SET V.V_QUANTITY=(SELECT    
      CASE    
      WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >=S.QUANTITY AND V.VEHICLE_ID=S.VEHICLE_ID_FK THEN V.V_QUANTITY-S.QUANTITY    
      WHEN V.V_QUANTITY<S.QUANTITY THEN S.QUANTITY END  
      FROM VEHICLE V,V_SALE S    
      WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID=S.VEHICLE_ID_FK)   
      WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID=:NEW.VEHICLE_ID_FK;  
      END;
```

As you asked for IF ELSE Example am adding this sample example and apply as per your need,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TRG_PAYMONEY" 
AFTER INSERT
ON PAYMENTDEVICE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.MEALTYPE='GUEST' THEN
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = CREDIT - 5
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
ELSE
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = CREDIT - CHARGE
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: @Mari I am still getting those errors:/

Comment: @Ben Sorry I didnt notice it. Corrected it now. Can you review it. Thanks..

Comment: @Mari Compilation failed, line 9 (16:29:59) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. 
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'V' reference is out of scope
Compilation failed, line 3 (16:29:59) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'V' reference is out of scope
Compilation failed, line 2 (16:29:59) 
PL/SQL: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this

Comment: @notfound90 pls wait am looking into this

Comment: I dont find anything wrong with this @notfound90. Is that select statement is running without any error?

Comment: @Mari Can we write same thing with if then else statements.

Comment: yeah we can. I ll post you a sample code. Can you follow up that? See my updated answer

Comment: @notfound90 it works now?? Can you show me the final working code?

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt you just need this?

```
UPDATE VEHICLE V   
     SET V.V_QUANTITY=CASE WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >= :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN V.V_QUANTITY-:NEW.QUANTITY    
                                  WHEN V.V_QUANTITY < :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN :NEW.QUANTITY   
                              END
   WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID = :NEW.VEHICLE_ID_FK;
```

Comment: I also tried this code but got the Error: subprogram or cursor 'V' reference is out of scope

Comment: You're not trying very hard to help yourself @notfound90; change `update vehicle`  to `update vehicle v` or remove all the `v.`.

Comment: @notfound90 added the alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace TRIGGER "TRG_DecreaseQuantity"
AFTER INSERT
ON V_SALE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN     
     UPDATE VEHICLE V    
     SET V.V_QUANTITY=CASE WHEN V.V_QUANTITY >= :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN V.V_QUANTITY-:NEW.QUANTITY    
                                  WHEN V.V_QUANTITY < :NEW.QUANTITY 
                                  THEN V.V_QUANTITY   
                              END
   WHERE V.VEHICLE_ID = :NEW.VEHICLE_ID_FK;
END;
```